# Array of primitives or objects initialization

Tags: java, string, initialization

Array of String objects can be created as

// Acceptable declarations and initialization

```
line 1: String[]s = new String[2];
line 2: String[]s = new String[]{"a","b"};
```

// Below init also looks good to me but compiler errors out

```
line 3: String[] s = new String[2] { "a", "b" };
```

1) Why cant i specify the size of the array in **line 3**?
2) When I create an array using line 3, are strings "a" and "b" created on heap or in String pool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can't both initialize an array and specify its size, that would just be redundant.
2. All string literals are stored in the constant pool and that happens before your code runs, at class loading time.

Also note that even `new String[]` is redundant with an initializer:

```
String[] s = {"a","b"};
```

Comment: that should be choice for programmer isnt it? like in Java 7  allows diamond operator declaration and regular declartion(java 6 style)

Comment: Not only would it be redundant, but also the compiler would have to check for an error like `String[] s = new String[2] { "a", "b", "c" };`

Comment: @lordlupine The fact that Java 6 mandates redundancy is not exactly a feather in its hat. That's why the diamond operator was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in order to prevent ambiguity.

What should the system do if the number in [] and the actual number of objects you pass doesn't match?

So, the size of your array is defined by the number of object you pass to the initializer.

---

Second question is a bit incorrect. 
Java objects are ALWAYS created on the heap.

The String objects in your case are taken from the pool of String objects, because you use literals and compiler can easily realize what their values at run-time will be.